# How to define rails observers path in application.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I just want to define my all observer in single line now i have code like this  `config.active_record.observers = :user_observer, :studet_observer, :suggestion_observer,
        :progress_observer, :admin_observer, :employee_observer, :update_message_observer,
        :test_observer, :question_observer, :exam_observer, :coach_observer, :wordpress_post_observer,
        :answer_observer , :doubt_observer, :doubt_reply_observer, :image_format_observer #FIXME`
,  Is this possible to define like this  `config.active_record.observers_path = /app/observers`

Answer (score 0):

Just do `config.autoload_paths += [#{config.root}/app/observers]` in config/application.rb

Comment: It's not working, I tried following three types

`config.autoload_paths += ["#{config.root}/app/observers"]`
  `config.autoload_paths += "#{config.root}/app/observers"`
  `config.autoload_paths += "#{Rails.root}/app/observers"`
 help me.

Comment: This case `config.autoload_paths += ["#{Rails.root}/app/observers"]`  in my config.autoload_path contain `["/home/hulk/workspace/app_name/lib", "/home/hulk/workspace/app_name/app/observers"]` these two paths

Answer (score 0):

I did this using Dir, File functions, It's Working

```
config.active_record.observers = Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/observers/*.rb"].map{|file| File.basename(file, '.rb').to_sym}
```